# How to create clean URL in rails nested resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I have two controller `Stores` and `Stocks` and routes for these two controller is given below:

```
  resources :stores do
    resources :stocks,param: :product_id,:only=>[:index] do
      get '/:product_id', to: 'stocks#index'
    end
  end
```

After `rake routes` I'm getting the path like:

`GET    /stores/:store_id/stocks/:stock_id/:product_id(.:format)`

But I want to remove `:stock_id` from that path so that the resultant path will be:

`GET    /stores/:store_id/stocks/:product_id(.:format)`

If it's possible then please help.

Comment: But if a product is nested under a certain stock, how will you identify the product without giving a stock ID?

Comment: No, actually I need all stocks for that particular product of that store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
resources :stores do
  resources :stocks, except: :index do
    get '/:product_id', to: 'stocks#index', on: :collection
  end
end
```

This will give you:

```
GET  /stores/:store_id/stocks/:product_id(.:format)   stocks#index
```

if you want default index action also then:

```
resources :stores do
  resources :stocks do
    get '/:product_id', to: 'stocks#index', on: :collection
  end
end
```

This will give you both index:

```
              GET  /stores/:store_id/stocks/:product_id(.:format)  stocks#index
store_stocks  GET  /stores/:store_id/stocks(.:format)              stocks#index
```